# Selenium/Junit/pageObject: NPE, when calling method, which clicks on element created via @FindBy annotation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have following classes:

Test class, for tests runs:

```
public class MainPageTest {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private MainPage mainPage;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://github.com");
        mainPage = new MainPage(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void signInTest() {
        mainPage.clickSignIn();
    }
}
```

and `MainPage`, where `clickSignIn()` and needed element described:
(returned `LoginPage` does not impact current use-case.)

```
public class MainPage {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='Sign in']")
    private WebElement signInButton;

    public LoginPage clickSignIn() {
        signInButton.click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']")).click();
        return new LoginPage(driver);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to run @Test - it fails with NPE

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at MainPage.clickSignIn(MainPage.java:33)
>     at MainPageTest.signInTest(MainPageTest.java:29)

But if we'll change method in MainPage to

```
public LoginPage clickSignIn() {
    //signInButton.click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']")).click();
    return new LoginPage(driver);
}
```

the test passed as green (button clicked successfully).

So, question: how I should correctly use `@FindBy` annotation, to create/find needed webElements, for using them in methods just by names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the initElements method on PageFactory object inside your MainPage class constructor.

```
public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
```

`PageFactory.initElements` initialises the elements that you decorated with the `@FindBy` annotation. If you don't use `PageFactory` and you don't manually initialise the element (by e.g. assign a value) a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.